# How to build a monitoring system with an infra cam?

Tags: camera

I need to place 2 USB (?) webcams that are looking at two doors. No sound needed, just a few things:

- video files must be saved at least for 30 days (I have two eee pc's for the two webcams, so cable length doesn't matter)
- video quality must be good enough [@night too! - infra cam needed]
- timestamp on the video image

I have a netbook that can do the recording. OS: **OpenBSD**

Comment: It is hard to see the connection to Unix or Linux at your question.

Comment: Why do you need to place the webcams?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not use an USB webcam for it. Especially since the size limit of those (5m indeed). Also each webcam would require a seperate controller due to the bandwidth requirements.

Software like motion also supports IP webcams that output an MJPEG stream.

Consider buying a webcam with infrared leds unless the lighting is always guaranteed to be good. Well unless you decide to go for a Philips USB webcam with PWC chipset: those handle bad lighting pretty good. Other's produce lots of noise which gives problems when detecting motion.

Had very good experience with http://www.lavrsen.dk/foswiki/bin/view/Motion/WebHome (but I might be a little prejudiced).

Answer (score 3):

You can try a [ZoneMinder](http://www.zoneminder.com/) SW...

Answer (score 1):

Other than zoneminder, which may be a bit overkill, try `motion` should be in the fedora repos, and is kicking about for rhel5 somewhere.